# ASP.NET Web API - Getting AspNetInitializationExceptionModule after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, asp.net-web-api

I wrote REST service using ASP.NET Web API

I’ve also set “copy local” property of the below libraries to true.

> System.Web.Mvc  System.Web.Routing  System.Web.Abstractions

I deployed it using visual studio publish tool through FTP to my hosting account.

However, when I open this service in browser, I get the following error:

> **HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
>
> Module    AspNetInitializationExceptionModule
>
> Notification  BeginRequest
>
> Handler   StaticFile
>
> Error Code    0x00000000**

Would you have any suggestions what may be wrong? I cannot solve it on my own so far and it really blocks me.

Greetings

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Can you post some info from the event viewer?? Also do you have the server with the latest window update? Some weird erros are fixed by them.

Comment: Web API is part of asp.net 4.5, you sure you have 4.5 installed correctly and it's isapi is registered?

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.iis.net/t/1159785.aspx seems to suggest you need to run aspnet_regiis -i as an administrator to fix this.

Comment: Actually, the last comment on that page points out that it didn't work.